# Angular Directive not interpolating variables properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is a fiddle describing this issue, the second node should have 4 values but only displays 1:

https://jsfiddle.net/mbaranski/akcz3569/

I have an angular directive:

```
var OrgChartDirective = function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        scope: {
            source     : '=',
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var target = $(element);
            var source = $('#' + scope.source);
            var options = {
                container  : target,
            };
            console.log("Drawing org chart at :");
            console.log(element);
            console.log("Source is " + scope.source);
            source.orgChart(options);
        }
    }
};
```

This draws an org chart based on a nested UL that I have on the page.  Works great for a static list, but if I draw the list with an angular ng-repeat, it does not show the list, it only shows the `{{whatever}}` text.  How do I make the directive use the **rendered data** instead of the raw template data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `$timeout` to let the ng-repeat render. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/akcz3569/7/

```
$timeout(function() {
  source.orgChart(options);
});
```

Comment: OK, that works in that case.  Problem is I have a template rendering recursively to build the list, and I need to wait for that to finish.  You fixed the fiddle, but how to I make the timeout wait until another partial has fully rendered?

Comment: The way mine is rendering, if I set the timeout to 5 seconds, it renders properly.  How can I make it wait until the recursive templates render?

Comment: Do you have to use a DOM-based data source to create the org chart? You have the data in the code, why not set up the data source there and call the `orgChart()` when it's ready? If you are absolutely forced to use a DOM-based data source, I would recommend building it yourself in JS and not relying on `ng-repeat` to do it for you, as I am not aware of any way to hook into a `ng-repeat` `onRendered` event. If it does exist, though, you could call `orgChart()` from there. If you could simulate your recursive template rendering `ng-repeat` in jsFiddle, I will look into it further.

Comment: I'll see if I can do that in the fiddle.  That's a pretty big black mark for Angular, in my book.  I am using `ng-repeat` recursively, but there ought to be a way to bind my `orgChart()` call so that it updates when the data changes in the `ng-repeat`

Comment: Consider using `$scope.$watch()` to watch the `dataArray` and remake the `orgChart` when it changes. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch